# Good forums for Thai learners?

Tags: thai

Since "Thai Language" in Area 51 disappeared, I assume that SE does not intend/plan to be a home for questions related to Thai language (I hope I am wrong).

I found several forums related to Thailand as country/culture/visas, and Thai as language, but those are old-school forums with no voting, distracted debates, etc - we all know why SE is better than traditional forums.

More popular forums I found are:

- [Thailand Visa Forum by Thai Visa](https://forum.thaivisa.com/) and
- [thai-language.com - Forums](http://www.thai-language.com/forums).

Is this the best there is, or are some other hidden gems I am missing?

Comment: Area 51 removes proposals for inactivity. I was the OP of 2 or 3 Thai Language proposals back in 2014,2016 and there was simply too few prominent people who contribute example questions and join discussions to shape the future site. Nothing prevents you or me to start over, but keep in mind that promotion is the key.

Comment: You basically need an established group of people who want a SE forum. Then make the proposal and get all of them active on it.

Comment: I know I need lots of people with interests. But it is a "chicken and egg" problem. There is not that many Thai learners, or Thais hanging around and answering the questions on other forums. Even for Ukrainian language (40M speakers, and lots of programmers, so more potential users), the forum was quite moribund, IIRC. Thai language (same 40M speakers) has much bigger hurdles to overcome (economical, social: food service personnel does not frequent SO). So it only makes sense to start it if I have MUCH better plan for promoting it than the elders like @bytebuster had. Just brainstorming.

Answer (score 2):

Found this:

- [Learn Thai on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnthai/): looks very active, but of course format is very different.
- [Farang Can Learn Thai Language รักภาษาไทย](https://www.facebook.com/groups/faranglearnthai/): a private group on Facebook.